# gRPC c++ helloworld example has a compilation error

Tags: c++, grpc

I am trying out the gRPC helloworld example but when I run `make` I get the following error :

```
$ make
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/greeter_server.dir/greeter_server.cc.o
In file included from ./grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.grpc.pb.h:22,
                 from ./grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_server.cc:30:
./grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.pb.h:48:51: error: ‘AuxiliaryParseTableField’ in namespace ‘google::protobuf::internal’ does not name a type
   static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::AuxiliaryParseTableField aux[]
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.pb.h:48:16: note: suggested alternative: ‘AuxillaryParseTableField’
   static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::AuxiliaryParseTableField aux[]
                ^~
                AuxillaryParseTableField
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/greeter_server.dir/build.make:95: CMakeFiles/greeter_server.dir/greeter_server.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:103: CMakeFiles/greeter_server.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

This is the generated helloworld.pb.h :

```
#include <google/protobuf/port_undef.inc>
#include <google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h>
#include <google/protobuf/arena.h>
#include <google/protobuf/arenastring.h>
#include <google/protobuf/generated_message_table_driven.h>
#include <google/protobuf/generated_message_util.h>
#include <google/protobuf/inlined_string_field.h>
#include <google/protobuf/metadata_lite.h>
#include <google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h>
#include <google/protobuf/message.h>
#include <google/protobuf/repeated_field.h>  // IWYU pragma: export
#include <google/protobuf/extension_set.h>  // IWYU pragma: export
#include <google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.h>
// @@protoc_insertion_point(includes)
#include <google/protobuf/port_def.inc>
#define PROTOBUF_INTERNAL_EXPORT_helloworld_2eproto
PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_OPEN
namespace internal {
class AnyMetadata;
}  // namespace internal
PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_CLOSE

// Internal implementation detail -- do not use these members.
struct TableStruct_helloworld_2eproto {
  static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::ParseTableField entries[]
    PROTOBUF_SECTION_VARIABLE(protodesc_cold);
  static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::AuxiliaryParseTableField aux[]
    PROTOBUF_SECTION_VARIABLE(protodesc_cold);
  static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::ParseTable schema[2]
    PROTOBUF_SECTION_VARIABLE(protodesc_cold);
  static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::FieldMetadata field_metadata[];
  static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::SerializationTable serialization_table[];
  static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::uint32 offsets[];
};
extern const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::DescriptorTable descriptor_table_helloworld_2eproto;
namespace helloworld {
class HelloReply;
class HelloReplyDefaultTypeInternal;
extern HelloReplyDefaultTypeInternal _HelloReply_default_instance_;
class HelloRequest;
class HelloRequestDefaultTypeInternal;
extern HelloRequestDefaultTypeInternal _HelloRequest_default_instance_;
}  // namespace helloworld
PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_OPEN
template<> ::helloworld::HelloReply* Arena::CreateMaybeMessage<::helloworld::HelloReply>(Arena*);
template<> ::helloworld::HelloRequest* Arena::CreateMaybeMessage<::helloworld::HelloRequest>(Arena*);
PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_CLOSE
namespace helloworld {

// ===================================================================
...
```

I didn't edit anything in any of the file. I followed the lesson on the [grpc.io website](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/)

Comment: Protobuf renamed `AuxillaryParseTableField` to `AuxiliaryParseTableField` in version 3.12.3.

Comment: I see but don't you mean `AuxiliaryParseTableField` to `AuxillaryParseTableField` because this way it works

Comment: No because `Auxiliary` is the right spelling, but that it works with `Auxillary` means just that you now made it work with the old version that used the wrong spelling, apparently ^^

Comment: Yeah you are right. I had to reinstall both protobuf and grpc for everything to compile properly. Thanks.

Comment: This commit changed the spelling involved in the error: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/commit/2ae7cf0e03c3469973e592e812565e4ee2470e0b


The commit is tagged with the version 3.12.3. However, the tagging was wrong for 3.12.X and should not include this commit. So the team released a 3.12.4 version without this commit and some others. (https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/7632#issuecomment-666764578).

So a program compiled with the version 3.12.3 will not be compatible with the version 3.12.4.